# bind store to gridpanel combobox column extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, store

I'd like to dynamically bind store to combobox in my gridpanel using Extjs 4 and the MVC architecture, I did this in the clic handler of a button  :

```
var prodRelStore = this.getGetProdRelDataStore();   
var mygridprodrel = scopegrid.getView().getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(2);//the combo column
    prodRelStore.getProxy().url = 'getprodrel.php';
    prodRelStore.autoSync = true;
    prodRelStore.load({
    params: {
            scope_name: scopename
            },
            scope : this
    });
    mygridprodrel.bindStore(prodRelStore);
    scopegrid.getView().refresh();
```

But I get : `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bindStore'`
What is the right way to dynamically bind a store to a combobox inside a gridpanel?

Comment: I was looking for `bindStore` documentation and I think you need to call `bindStore` to combobox instance. If you want to make the column editable with a combobox which has a dynamically store, you have to add an editor to the column.

Comment: Something like this: 

`columns: [{ 
          text: 'Name',  
          dataIndex: 'name',
          editor: {
              xtype: 'comboxbox'
          }
}]`